# LARAVEL- Problema al leer hora desde BD

Tags: laravel, carbon, date-format

Utilizo Carbon para establecer el formato de la hora al momento de guardar ese dato en la base de datos MySQL. Pero al querer leerla obtengo el siguiente error.

***Failed to parse time string (--:--) at position 0 (-): Unexpected character***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explico, estoy haciendo un sistema de registro de citas médicas para mis estudios. Hay médicos que atienden a los pacientes en la mañana, solo en la tarde o durante el día completo. Y para establecer los horarios los guardo de esta manera.

Por ejemplo:

```
           dia | activo | inicio_dia | fin_dia | inicio_tarde | fin_tarde | id_usuario
Lunes      0   |   1    |   09:00    |  11:30  |    --:--     |   --:--   |    3
Martes     1   |   0    |   --:--    |  --:--  |    14:00     |   19:00   |    3
Miércoles  2   |   1    |   09:00    |  --:--  |    14:00     |   19:00   |    3
```

Para este ejemplo el medico Psicólogo atiende los lunes solo en la mañana, los martes solo en la tarde y los miércoles el día completo. El guardado de los datos me funciona sin problemas, es al leerlo que falla, y ciertamente es por el dato --:-- que no es reconocido como un formato de hora válido.

Dejo el código de guardar y editar (quiero traer los datos desde la BD y falla ahi).

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $usr = DB::TABLE('users')
    ->join('tipo_usuarios','users.tipo_usuario_id','=','tipo_usuarios.id_tipo_usuarios')
    ->join('medicos', 'users.id','=','medicos.usuario_id')
    ->join('especialidad', 'medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("medicos.id_doctor, CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_doctor,especialidad.nombre_especialidad,tipo_usuario_id,name,users.id,email,nivel")
    ->where('users.tipo_usuario_id','=',2)
    ->orderBy('users.id')
    ->get();

    $medico_id = $request->medic_id;

    $nombre_medico = DB::TABLE('medicos')
    ->JOIN('especialidad','medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellidos) AS 'doctor', especialidad.nombre_especialidad, ");

    $activo = $request->input('dias_medico') ?: [];
    $inicio_dia = $request->input('inicio_turno_dia');
    $fin_dia = $request->input('fin_turno_dia');

    $inicio_tarde = $request->input('inicio_turno_tarde');
    $fin_tarde = $request->input('fin_turno_tarde');

    $dia_inactivo_inicio = "--:--";
    $dia_inactivo_fin = "--:--";
    $tarde_inactivo_inicio = "--:--";
    $tarde_inactivo_fin = "--:--";

    
    for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 
        // code...
    
        Horarios::updateOrCreate([

            'dia' => $i,
            'id_usuario' => $medico_id,

        ],
        [
            'activo' => in_array($i, $activo),
            'inicio_turno_dia' => $inicio_dia[$i],
            'fin_turno_dia' => $fin_dia[$i],
            'inicio_turno_tarde' => $inicio_tarde[$i],
            'fin_turno_tarde' => $fin_tarde[$i],
        ]);
    }
    

    return view('secretaria.medicos', ['nombre_medico'=>$nombre_medico, 'usr'=>$usr])->with('success','Horario actualizado');
}
```

Función editar.

```
public function edit(Medicos $medicos){

    $datos = DB::table('medicos')
    ->join('especialidad','medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("medicos.id_doctor AS doctor_id, medicos.nombre AS doctor, medicos.apellidos AS surname, CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_medico, rut, fecha_nacimiento, especialidad.nombre_especialidad AS especialidad, especialidad_id")
    ->where('medicos.id_doctor', '=' ,$medicos->id_doctor)->first();
    
    $dias = ['Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domigo'];

    $horarios = Horarios::where('id_usuario',$medicos->id_doctor)->get();

    $horarios->map(function($horarios){

        $horarios->inicio_turno_dia = (new Carbon($horarios->inicio_turno_dia))->format('g:i A');
        $horarios->fin_turno_dia = (new Carbon($horarios->fin_turno_dia))->format('g:i A');

        $horarios->inicio_turno_tarde = (new Carbon($horarios->inicio_turno_tarde))->format('g:i A');
        $horarios->fin_turno_tarde = (new Carbon($horarios->fin_turno_tarde))->format('g:i A');

    });

    return view('forms.editar-horarios', compact('datos','medicos','dias','horarios'));
}
```

Utilizo ese formato (g:i A) para guardar las horas, como muestro en el ejemplo.

De todas formas, leo la documentación para hallar alguna solución.
[Documentación Carbon (inglés)](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

No entiendo bien que puedo hacer para solucionar el problema, hasta el momento entiendo que al registrar la hora así: **--:--** arroja un error porque no es un formato de hora válido, lo hice de esa forma porque intento representar que esa "hora" del médico no existe o no está ocupada por ese médico, *si se quiere entender de otra forma.*

Comment: no me gustan las descripciones de los errores que saca laravel, puedes hacer dd($variable) antes de que se rompa por favor y muestra que sale en el debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy bien entrego una solución a mi pregunta que explicaré a continuación.

**Un paréntesis.**

[ En relación al comentario de un usuario que me sugirió usar "00:00" aclaro que no me servía a mi mostrar 12:00 AM, mi intención era registrar los turnos de mañana y/o tarde que el médico no atiende. Porque como expliqué hay médicos que atienden en la mañana, solamente en la tarde o el día completo, que en mi caso establecí desde 09:00 AM hasta 18:00 PM con hora colación. Uso carbon para convertir el formato de 24Hrs a 12Hrs sin mostrar los segundos.

Por eso si registraba *(ya lo había hecho así antes de publicar esta pregunta)* **00:00:00** eso es una hora, significa 12:00 AM, tuve una confusión difícil con eso, y llegué a la conclusion que no me servía así porque al mostrar ese dato al usuario, me mostraba 12:00 AM debido a la conversión con Carbon. ]

**Ahora explico.** Se trata de un método sencillo y directo. Que aclaro no es el único, y si alguien conoce otra forma siéntase en la libertad de publicar una respuesta o comentario. No hay problema y se lo agradezco, así no solamente me ayuda a mí, también ayuda a otros usuarios.

Anteriormente, recuerdo bien que alguien más me dejo una respuesta que marqué como buena, pero no la veo, en esa ocasión me explicó que puedo dejar como *NULL* el dato para representar que el turno no está disponible y mostrar al usuario otra información, que en mi caso muestro la frase *"Sin Horario"* y ya la tenía así de ese modo con esa frase al momento de elaborar esta pregunta pero el *option* con valor *--:--* y no con valor nulo.

Comparto el código.

```
@foreach($horarios as $num_dias => $turno)
    <tr id="columnaHover">
      <th class="align-middle">{{$dias[$num_dias]}}</th>
      <td class="align-middle">                 
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{$num_dias}}" id="dias_medico" name="dias_medico[]" @if($turno->activo) checked @endif >
      </td>
            
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Inicio">

            @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00">{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30">{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
            @endfor
              <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
@endforeach
```

Eso es una parte, de una tabla y un formulario con destino a una ruta (store). La etiqueta **td** donde está la etiqueta *div* con clase "row" se repite 4 veces, para indicar el turno de inicio y termino de la mañana (respectivamente) y los turnos de inicio y término de la tarde. Que al revisar bien el código se pueden dar cuenta que la condición **@for** comienza la variable **$i** con el valor de 9 y llega hasta 11, y en la tarde comienza desde 2 hasta 6 cambiando luego el valor del option que se muestra al usuario entre AM y PM respectivamente.

Muestro así para acortar un poco el código. Ahora muestro como se guarda esta información en el controlador de los horarios.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Carbon\Carbon;

public function store(Request $request){

    $usr = DB::TABLE('users')
    ->join('tipo_usuarios','users.tipo_usuario_id','=','tipo_usuarios.id_tipo_usuarios')
    ->join('medicos', 'users.id','=','medicos.usuario_id')
    ->join('especialidad', 'medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("medicos.id_doctor, CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_doctor,especialidad.nombre_especialidad,tipo_usuario_id,name,users.id,email,nivel")
    ->where('users.tipo_usuario_id','=',2)
    ->orderBy('users.id')
    ->get();

    $medico_id = $request->medic_id;

    $nombre_medico = DB::TABLE('medicos')
    ->JOIN('especialidad','medicos.especialidad_id','=','especialidad.id_especialidad')
    ->selectRaw("CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellidos) AS 'doctor', especialidad.nombre_especialidad, ");

    $activo = $request->input('dias_medico') ?: [];
    $inicio_dia = $request->input('inicio_turno_dia');
    $fin_dia = $request->input('fin_turno_dia');

    $inicio_tarde = $request->input('inicio_turno_tarde');
    $fin_tarde = $request->input('fin_turno_tarde');

    $dia_inactivo_inicio = " ";
    $dia_inactivo_fin = " ";
    $tarde_inactivo_inicio = " ";
    $tarde_inactivo_fin = " ";

    
    for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 
        // code...
    
        Horarios::updateOrCreate([

            'dia' => $i,
            'id_usuario' => $medico_id,

        ],
        [
            'activo' => in_array($i, $activo),
            'inicio_turno_dia' => $inicio_dia[$i],
            'fin_turno_dia' => $fin_dia[$i],
            'inicio_turno_tarde' => $inicio_tarde[$i],
            'fin_turno_tarde' => $fin_tarde[$i],
        ]);
    }
    

    return redirect('/secretaria/medicos')->with('success','Horario actualizado');
}
```

La variable $inicio_dia y $fin_dia trae el valor del option respectivamente. Y luego dentro del **for** se guarda esa información para los 7 días de la semana, que aclaro que ocupo un checkbox para la validación de los días activos e inactivos del médico.

Y de esa forma rápida y sencilla logré solucionar el problema, al registrar los turnos inactivos como valores nulos, tuve que modificar la base de datos para que permitiera registrar valores nulos.

Pido atención en un **option** con la frase *Sin horario* en donde anteriormente tenía el atributo **value** con valor **--:--** que cambié a valor nulo, " " comillas dobles con espacio. En caso no hayan visto. Y fue así como se solucionó al momento de leer los datos.

Como dije no es el único método de solucionar esto. Hay otros que me comentó un usuario, pero no veo su respuesta que marqué (pienso que quizás alguien la borró, y desconozco la razón); y no recuerdo bien esas otras soluciones por eso dije que quien quiera comentar alguna solución diferente puede hacerlo es libre.

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tienes porque estás agregando un string a un atributo en tu base de datos que es de tipo ***time***: `$dia_inactivo_inicio = "--:--";`

Te recomiendo que intentes guardar el tiempo de esta manera `$dia_inactivo_inicio = "00:00";` cuando estas se quedan vacías.

Comment: Saludos, mmm. Creo que tenía ya una respuesta aceptada de un amigo que me dijo como solucionar ese problema. Y no la veo, vaya. Yo mismo responderé mi pregunta, con el método más directo y sencillo. Y respondiendo a tu respuesta no no puedo hacerlo así, es más ya lo hice en un principio cuando publique esto. Pero si te fijas "00:00" eso es una hora, 12:00 AM por eso no lo hice así, no me servía que me mostrara esa hora.