# Uso de condiciones Blade falla al mostrar datos - LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Bien explico, como en otras preguntas que ya he realizado y dejo el enlace a continuación:

[LARAVEL - Problema al leer la hora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601231/laravel-problema-al-leer-hora-desde-bd)

El asunto es que en esa pregunta ya había explicado mi propósito general del sitio web que estoy programando, así que ahora seré más breve para explicar el contexto general nuevamente.

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de registro de citas médicas, estoy en el desarrollo del módulo de los horarios de los médicos que el usuario con rol *secretaría* puede modificar, intento mostrar la información del usuario.

Por ejemplo, para un médico Psicólogo que atiende solo los lunes, martes y miércoles.

```
           dia | activo | inicio_dia | fin_dia | inicio_tarde | fin_tarde | id_usuario
Lunes      0   |   1    |   09:00    |  11:30  |    NULL      |   NULL    |    3
Martes     1   |   0    |   NULL     |  NULL   |    NULL      |   NULL    |    3
Miércoles  2   |   1    |   NULL     |  NULL   |    14:00     |   19:00   |    3
```

El lunes, solo atiende las mañanas luego, el miércoles atiende solo las tardes y el martes no atiende. La base de datos tiene esa información y cuando quiero mostrar me sale lo siguiente.

Adjunto una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese texto extraño es más bien la condición **blade** que está dentro de la etiqueta **option** y me sale así porque intento concatenar la variable $i con la hora, con la intención de que me muestre los horarios de acuerdo al turno de día. En realidad, esa forma extraña de usar condiciones la obtuve de un sujeto de unos videos con buen contenido en Youtube y el no responde los comentarios, en el último tiempo ha estado muy inactivo, como a mi no me funciona así, lo corregí cambiándolo a otra forma, y además me permite usar la condición **@else**

Primero muestro el código como era en un principio. Corresponde a parte de una tabla con un formulario que tiene como destino una ruta (store).

```
@foreach($horarios as $num_dias => $turno)
<tr id="columnaHover">
  <th class="align-middle">{{$dias[$num_dias]}}</th>
  <td class="align-middle">                 
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{$num_dias}}" id="dias_medico" name="dias_medico[]" @if($turno->activo) checked @endif >
  </td>
<td>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Inicio">

      @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
        <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" @if($i.':00  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) selected @endif>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
        <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" @if($i.':30  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) selected @endif>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
      @endfor
        <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
                                    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <select class="form-control" name="fin_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Fin">
      @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
        <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" @if($i.':00  AM') == $turno->fin_turno_dia) selected @endif>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
        <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" @if($i.':30  AM') == $turno->fin_turno_dia) selected @endif>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
      @endfor
        <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
@endforeach
```

Pero luego de corregir el código, a como es lo correcto en relación a buenas prácticas y código ordenado o si alguno piensa que igual está bien la otra forma usando condiciones blade dentro de etiquetas me explique correctamente porque estaría bien para entender.

Si no es el caso, yo lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach($horarios as $num_dias => $turno)
<tr id="columnaHover">
  <th class="align-middle">{{$dias[$num_dias]}}</th>
    <td class="align-middle">                 
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{$num_dias}}" id="dias_medico" name="dias_medico[]" @if($turno->activo) checked @endif >
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Inicio">

          @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
            @if($i.':00  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) 
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" selected>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
            @else
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00">{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
            @endif
                                                    

            @if($i.':30  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" selected>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
            @else
              <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30">{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
            @endif
          @endfor
          <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
    
  <td>                                 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <select class="form-control" name="fin_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Fin">
        @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
          @if($i.':00  AM') == $turno->fin_turno_dia)
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" selected>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
          @else
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00">{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
          @endif

                                                    
          @if($i.':30  AM') == $turno->fin_turno_dia)
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" selected>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
          @else
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30">{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
          @endif
        @endfor
        <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
@endforeach
```

Pero ahora me muestra mal la hora, cuando debería estar bien, pienso yo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no es así, además aún no he pensado la forma de agregar la condición para que valide los días inactivos con turnos libres (dato NULL) y los muestre, porque en el ejemplo martes debería estar con la frase *"Sin horario"* que es la frase que muestro cuando el valor es nulo.

Me gustaría conocer la forma de hacerlo bien y ciertamente distinto a como lo hice. Porque de la forma que lo hizo el sujeto y que no logro comprender por qué a él si le funciona.
Siendo eso todo, gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: La condicion va entre parentesis `@if($i.':00  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia)` sería `@if($i.':00  AM' == $turno->inicio_turno_dia)` o `@if(($i.':00  AM') == $turno->inicio_turno_dia)`

Answer (score 1):

una buena práctica sería crear una tabla con un formato diferente que sólo tenga Día, doctor_id(aquí sería el id del doctor), hora de inicio, hora de fin. Si es tarde se sabría por la hora y te ahorras una validación. También cree una aplicación web para laravel y lo hice así:

```
            <div class="modal" id="modalShifts">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Horario de Atención</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="father">
                        @foreach($shifts as $shift)
                        <div id="{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="shift_id{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" value="{{ $shift->id }}">
                                <label class="mb-2">Día</label>
                                <select class="form-control selShift" name="Day{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" id="Day{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" onchange="validateShift(this);" onclick="selDayClick();">
                                    <option value="{{ $shift->Day }}">{{ $shift->Day }}</option>
                                    <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
                                    <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
                                    <option value="Miercoles">Miercoles</option>
                                    <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
                                    <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
                                    <option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>
                                    <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2.5">
                                <label class="mb-2">Inicio</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="TimeStart{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" type="time" id="TimeStart{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" onchange="checkStartEnd(this.parentElement);" value="{{ substr(strval($shift->TimeStart), 0, -3) }}" required>
                                <div id="ErrorTimeStart{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2.5">
                                <label class="mb-2">Salida</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="TimeEnd{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" type="time" id="TimeEnd{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" onchange="checkStartEnd(this.parentElement);" value="{{ substr(strval($shift->TimeEnd), 0, -3) }}" required>
                                <div id="ErrorTimeEnd{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            @if ($doctor->location == 'Ambas sedes')
                            <div class="col-md-2 pr-0">
                                <label class="mb-2">Sede</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" id="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" style="font-weight: bolder;" required>
                                    <option value="Principal"{{ $shift->location == 'Principal' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Monarca</option>
                                    <option value="Metropolitana"{{ $shift->location == 'Metropolitana' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Metropolitano</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            @elseif ($doctor->location == 'Principal')
                            <input type="hidden" name="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" id="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" value="Principal">
                            @elseif ($doctor->location == 'Metropolitana')
                            <input type="hidden" name="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" id="hlocation{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" value="Metropolitana">
                            @endif
                            
                            <div class="col-md-2 pr-0">
                                <label class="mb-2">Estado</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="Status{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" id="Status{{ $loop->iteration - 1 }}" style="font-weight: bolder;" required>
                                    <option value="{{ $shift->Status }}">{{ $shift->Status }}</option>
                                    <option style="color: red; font-weight: bolder;" value="No-Disponible">No Disponible</option>
                                    <option style="color: green; font-weight: bolder;" value="Disponible">Disponible</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 align-self-end">
                                <button id="btnDeleteShiftSaved" class="btn fas fa-trash mb-1" type="button"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach

                        <div id="{{ $shifts->count() }}" class="" style="margin-top:4%;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" onclick="newShift(this.parentElement);">Agregar Nuevo Turno</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="TotalShifts" value="{{ $shifts->count() + 1 }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currentShifts" id="currentShifts" value="{{ $services->count() }}">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Listo!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

En tu caso puede ser algo así:

```
@foreach($horarios as $num_dias => $turno)
<tr id="columnaHover">
  <th class="align-middle">{{$dias[$num_dias]}}</th>
  <td class="align-middle">                 
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{$num_dias}}" id="dias_medico" name="dias_medico[]" @if($turno->activo) checked @endif >
  </td>

  <td>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <select class="form-control" name="inicio_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Inicio">
          @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
            @php
              $selected = ($i.':00 AM' == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) || ($i.':30 AM' == $turno->inicio_turno_dia) ? 'selected' : '';
            @endphp
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
          @endfor
          <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>                                 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <select class="form-control" name="fin_turno_dia[]" title="Hora Fin">
          @for($i=9; $i<=11; $i++)
            @php
              $selected = ($i.':00 AM' == $turno->fin_turno_dia) || ($i.':30 AM' == $turno->fin_turno_dia) ? 'selected' : '';
            @endphp
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:00" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:00 AM</option>
            <option value="{{ ($i<10 ? '0' : '') . $i }}:30" {{$selected}}>{{$i}}:30 AM</option>
          @endfor
          <option value=" ">Sin Horario</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo y me gusta esa solución que propones yo agregue los turnos tarde y los muestra bien, pero hay un problema. Tengo datos _NULL_ y me debería mostrar **Sin Horario** y no **09:00 AM**, estoy viendo como arreglar eso. Pero si me puedes ayudar, estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Pero no entiendo para que el for y el condicional en la etiqueta option. Haz un foreach normal y muestra los campos correspondientes. Al traer a todos los psicologos y recorrer el array de todos los psicólogos se va a traer a los campos correspondientes. Creo que es la forma más sencilla. En caso de que los campos de hora estén en una tabla diferente, lo que puedes hacer es traer también la relación con una consulta del tipo Psicologos::whereHas('relacionDelModelo',function($q){  $q->where('id','Y'); })->get();
No sé si te ayude pero ésta consulta te traerá a todos los psicólogos que tengan un registro en la tabla "X", donde el campo ID (en la tabla X) sea Y.

De la misma forma, el resultado lo vas a recibir en una variable a la que puedes llamar $psicologos por ejemplo. Entonces recorres a la variable $psicologos de forma normal y accedes a sus campos.

Comment: Si eso lo enseñaba un sujeto que se cree tutor en un video de youtube, y lo vi para obtener ideas. Yo tampoco comprendía porque usar condicionales dentro de la etiqueta y le funciona así. Por eso separe como dices el condicional, entiendo tu idea y lo puedo intentar. Gracias